# Limit resource routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have below routes

```
resources :analytics do
collection do
  get 'group_image'
  get 'group_tag'
  get 'group_location'
  get 'group_time'
end
```

end

But it also creates default routes, which I don't need. How can I limit routes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `namespace` instead of `resources`:

```
namespace :analytics do
   get 'group_image'
   get 'group_tag'
   get 'group_location'
   get 'group_time'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
resources :analytics, only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'group_image'
    get 'group_tag'
    get 'group_location'
    get 'group_time'
  end
end
```

It will creates your custom routes, but not the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You can define like this also by excluding default actions.

```
resources :analytics, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy, :index] do
collection do
    get 'group_image'
    get 'group_tag'
    get 'group_location'
    get 'group_time'
  end
end
```